# Scoped vs Singleton ignite client node in .net web api

Tags: ignite

I am try planning to introduce Apache Ignite into existing old .net web api project to use it as key/value store for detecting duplicate requests sent to the load balanced api.

I would like to introduce minimum overhead to each request.

As I understand Client node is communicating to the server through TCP.

My current go to plan is to create a singleton object which will establish connection to the remote cache and register it in my DI container.

Is it ok to leave node running and TCP connection open or should make the ignite object scoped to start close on each request/response cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in open, as a singleton.

1. Ignite object is thread safe
2. It is expensive to create and connect to the cluster (in case of classic "Thick" client)

There is also a ["Thin" client](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/thin-client), which is very lightweight and *can* be created and disposed often. Note that thin client is also thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try to use REST:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api